# symfony FOSRestBundle depth

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle - with automatic rotues and automatic views. My action in Controller looks like this:

```
public function getAction($user_id)
{
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('SBGUserBundle:User')->find($user_id);
    return $user;
}
```

Everything is OK, my response in JSON format looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "username": "fwojciechowski",
    "mpks": [{
        "id": 91,
        "name": "Testowe MPK 1",
        "managers": []
    }, {
        "id": 92,
        "name": "Testowe MPK 2",
        "teta_id": 1,
        "managers": []
    }]
}
```

But I have to take 1 level depth more - i need "managers" in "mpks" array.
But I don't need 3 levels in other cases.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

## annotations

if you are using annotations you can do it like this yml configs later for reference.
first you go to the manager entity and add the following :

```
/**
 * Manager
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="manager")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Manager
{
......
      /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @Serializer\Expose
 * @Serializer\Groups({
 *     "user",
 * })
 */
private $id;
```

now you decide what properties you need from the managers and add the following before each entity

```
* @Serializer\Expose
* @Serializer\Groups({
*     "user",
* })
$property
```

then before your getAction you add this

```
/**
 * Get User.
 *
 * @param User $user
 *
 * @return User
 *
 * @Route\Get("/users", options={"expose"=true})
 *
 * @View(serializerGroups={"user"}) \\notice that its the same group name from before Serializer\Groups({"user"})
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 * ....
 * )
 */
public function getAction()
```

## yml

it should look something like this

```
Acme\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        username:
            expose: true
        mpks:
            expose: true
Acme\Manager
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        first_name:
            expose: true
        last_name:
            expose: true
        #and the rest of your wanted properties
```